# How to paste text in textbox current cursor?

Tags: c#, textbox

How do you paste text into a `TextBox` at the current cursor position in Windows Forms?

**Not** `textbox1 += string`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
var insertText = "Text";
var selectionIndex = textBox1.SelectionStart;
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(selectionIndex, insertText);
textBox1.SelectionStart = selectionIndex + insertText.Length;
```

Comment: Two things: first of all, is that a direct code sample? In C#, the keyword var isn't used to create a variable, instead precise datatypes are used. Thus, you would use *string insertText = "Text"; int selectionIndex = textBox1.SelectionStart;*. 2nd, you don't need to define as textBox1.SelectionStart as its own variable, you can just call it directly, but all this does is eliminate one line of code, so not very important. – Maximz2005 0 secs ago

Comment: `var` is new in C# 3.5 (or something), it's a sort of automatic type inference, saving you some typing. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

Comment: Anyway I don't see a point in using var when string will suffice.

Comment: yeah, but it's another way, it's your choice, you can use it or not. ;)

Comment: the real beauty of var comes in realize that c# is smart than you and it will manage the var variable more efficiently than you will.

Comment: `var` allows you to not repeat yourself in situations like `List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();`.

Comment: Another good use for `var` is when you're still deciding what concrete classes to use it helps avoid some changes (you have less hard-coded logic) for example when you alter a functions return type and receive the value in a `var x = functionCall();`.

Comment: Old I know, but addressing @MaximZaslavsky 2nd point; the SelectionStart is assigned to a variable to allow resetting of the cursor position as after setting the Text property the cursor position is reset to the start of the string. Note bsara's answer below alleviates all of this it seems.

Comment: Not sure why, but that didn't work for me with WPF's TextBox. Instead, used this code: `var before = textBox.Text.Substring(0, textBox.SelectionStart);
            var after = textBox.Text.Substring(textBox.SelectionStart);
            textBox.Text = before + inBetween + after;`

Answer (score 52):

A much easier way would be to use the `Paste` method:

```
  textbox1.Paste("text to insert");
```

I've done this using .NET 4.0

Comment: +1 It's much better, because it will not influence your cursor position and scrolling.

Comment: This is simple and perfectly working
With this;when you select some string you can overwrite to selected string

Answer (score 6):

I know this is late but the most efficient way appears to be:

```
textBox1.SelectedText = "Text";
```

Comment: how to implement same in asp.net because i didn't find SelectedText Property in asp.net TextBox Control

Comment: @Sri, clearly, since the ASP.NET Server has no information about the client (e.g. the cursor position). You should use JavaScript code for such actions.

Answer (score 5):

```
 textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(textBox1.SelectionStart, "Whatever");
```

Comment: why inserted cursor move to begin textbox?

Comment: how can cursor focus in insert after insert text

Comment: set `textBox1.SelectionStart` to whatever position you want.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to accomplish this is to use the **TextBox.Text.Insert(int indexSelectionStart, string text)**. What this method does is **insert text** into the TextBox **at the index you specify** - it uses `string string.insert(int startIndex, string value)` as TextBox.Text is a string which we are going to insert text into at a specific point. You wish to insert text **where the cursor/selector is**, and to find that index, we can use **TextBox.SelectionStart**.

Let's say that your TextBox is named textBox1.
This is what the code may look like, presuming that the text you wish to insert is stored in the string named *strInsert*.

```
string strInsert = "I am inserting this text.";
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(textBox1.SelectionStart, strInsert);
```

Answer (score 1):

This ensures that the cursor is at some position within the textbox, then inserts the text wherever the cursor is located.

```
        if (textBox1.CaretIndex <= 0)
        {

               textBox1.Focus();
     textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(
                textBox1.CaretIndex, "Whatever");
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(
                textBox1.CaretIndex, "Whatever");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple way would be

```
textBox1.Paste();
```

That replaces the current selection with the contents of the clipboard.

If you need to do it manually then it's a bit more work.  Remember if you're "pasting" then you are "replacing" the current selection if there is one.  So you need to handle that first.  You'll need to save SelectionStart if you had a selection as removing the text will screw it up.

```
string newText = "your text";

int start = textBox1.SelectionStart;

bool haveSelection = textBox1.SelectionLength > 0;

string text = (haveSelection) ? textBox1.Text.Remove(start,textBox1.SelectionLength) : textBox1.Text;

textBox1.Text = text.Insert(start,newText);

if(haveSelection)
{
    textBox1.SelectionStart = start;
    textBox1.SelectionLength = newText.Length;
}
```

After you're done you'll want to invalidate the control to force it to redraw.

```
textBox1.Invalidate();
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post but i hope this collection of methods for TextBox will help others struggling with manipulating this control.

```
public static class InputExtensions
{
    public static void InsertText(this TextBox textbox, string strippedText)
    {
        int start = textbox.SelectionStart;
        string newTxt = textbox.Text;
        newTxt = newTxt.Remove(textbox.SelectionStart, textbox.SelectionLength);
        newTxt = newTxt.Insert(textbox.SelectionStart, strippedText);
        textbox.Text = newTxt;
        textbox.SelectionStart = start + strippedText.Length;
    }

    public static void Delete(this TextBox textbox)
    {
        var startLength = textbox.Text.Length;
        if (textbox.Text.Length == 0) return;
        var isSelection = textbox.SelectionLength > 0;
        var length = Math.Max(!isSelection ? 1 : textbox.SelectionLength, 0);
        int start = textbox.SelectionStart;
        string newTxt = textbox.Text;
        if (length == 0 || start + length > startLength) return;
        newTxt = newTxt.Remove(start, length);
        textbox.Text = newTxt;
        textbox.SelectionStart = start;
    }

    public static void Backspace(this TextBox textbox)
    {
        var startLength = textbox.Text.Length;
        if (startLength == 0) return;
        var isSelection = textbox.SelectionLength > 0;
        var length = Math.Max(!isSelection ? 1 : textbox.SelectionLength, 0);
        int start = Math.Max(textbox.SelectionStart - 1, 0);
        if (length == 0 || start == 0) return;
        string newTxt = textbox.Text;
        newTxt = newTxt.Remove(start, length);
        textbox.Text = newTxt;
        textbox.SelectionStart = start;
    }

    public static void MoveCaretRight(this TextBox textbox)
    {
        textbox.SelectionStart = Math.Min(Math.Max(0, textbox.SelectionStart + 1), textbox.Text.Length);
    }

    public static void MoveCaretLeft(this TextBox textbox)
    {
        textbox.SelectionStart = Math.Min(Math.Max(0, textbox.SelectionStart - 1), textbox.Text.Length);
    }

    public static bool IsModifier(this KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        return e.Control || e.Alt || e.Shift;
    }

    public static bool IsNavigationKey(this KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.PageUp:
            case Keys.PageDown:
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool IsNonNumber(this KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var key = (char)e.KeyCode;
        return
            char.IsLetter(key) ||
            char.IsSymbol(key) ||
            char.IsWhiteSpace(key) ||
            char.IsPunctuation(key);
    }

    public static void Paste(TextBox textbox, Func<char, int, bool> charFilter = null)
    {
        var pasteText = Clipboard.GetText();
        var strippedText = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < pasteText.Length; i++)
        {
            if (charFilter == null || charFilter(pasteText[i], i))
                strippedText += pasteText[i].ToString();
        }
        InsertText(textbox, strippedText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
 string insertText = "Text";
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text+ insertText;
            textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length +1;
```