# .NET Multiline Textbox Make Shift+Enter working instead of Enter key

Tags: textbox, newline, multiline, shift, enter

I have a Windows Form Multiline Textbox.
I want to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> Instead of using Enter key to make a new line in textbox, and the traditional <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will be used to focus on the next control.
I mean <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will work exactly like <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on normal multiline textbox (Regard to textbox maxlength --> So you cant enter newline, or current selected text will be delete when you insert newline,...)

I've tried to override OnKeyDown, to insert newline on <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, but it doesn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need to override OnKeyDown and check for enter key using the KeyDownEvent's KeyCode property.

If enter was pressed and the keydownevent's modifiers property does not equal Keys.Shift you'll need to suppress the key press.  Here's the documentation on how to do that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress(v=vs.110).aspx

If shift+enter was pressed you'll need to insert Environment.NewLine at the cursor position, then move the cursor after the inserted Environment.NewLine.  Here's how to do that:

[How to paste text in textbox current cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416454/how-to-paste-text-in-textbox-current-cursor)

Comment: Many thank for your advice.
Yeah, I've override OnkeyDown to detect "Shift+Enter".
And when insert(paste) NewLine, I think we also have to regard to Maxlength of the textbox and current selected text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation in VB .NET.

Regard to Maxlength of the textbox and current selected text

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyDown(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
        If (Me.Multiline AndAlso e.KeyData = (Keys.Shift Or Keys.Enter)) Then
            Dim intRemainCharCount As Integer = Me.MaxLength - Me.Text.Length + Me.SelectedText.Length

            '' Check if have enough space to place NewLine
            If (Environment.NewLine.Length > intRemainCharCount) Then
                MyBase.OnKeyDown(e)
                Return
            End If

            Dim intPos = Me.SelectionStart

            Me.Paste(Environment.NewLine)

            '' Reset selection start (Reset cusor position)
            Me.SelectionStart = intPos + Environment.NewLine.Length

            e.Handled = True
            e.SuppressKeyPress = True
            Return
        End If

        MyBase.OnKeyDown(e)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the property for `Accept Return` for the Multiline doesn't even require coding anything, unless you have an event listening to the KeyDown, in which case you can put a condition to check if the `Textbox` is focussed.